# JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array

Tags: java, json, api, curl, httprequest

I am beginner to JAVA with API.

The response That I'm getting during my program as follows:

*Object Response:

```
    {
        "statusLine":{
            "reasonPhrase":"OK",
            "protocolVersion":{},
            "statusCode":200
        },
        "protocolVersion":{},
        "locale":"en_IN",
        "entity":{
            "repeatable":false,
            "content":{}
        }
    }
```

Exception Occured. JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.*

Unable to get full complete values in the results. I am getting only header details.

Please help me in get complete details from the API. using JAVA

```
package IOT;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class HttpPostWithBody {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String Message = "6f2159f998";

    try {
        new HttpPostWithBody().sendJSONData(Message);
    } catch (Exception E) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occured. " + E.getMessage());
    }
}

public String sendJSONData(String message) throws Exception {

    Map< String, Object> jsonValues = new HashMap< String, Object>();
    {
    jsonValues.put("thing_key", message);
    jsonValues.put("from", "2016/08/29 16:55:00");
    jsonValues.put("to", "2016/08/29 17:05:00");
    jsonValues.put("time_zone", "Mumbai");
    jsonValues.put("time_format", "str");
    jsonValues.put("per", 50);
    //jsonValues.put("metrics", "1st data");
    }
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonValues);

    String url = "https://api.datonis.io/api/v3/datonis_query/thing_data";

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", "YZ0Sa7IfpdtAXQQ-2CNeAg");

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF8");
    System.out.println("This is the entity: " + entity);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement je = jp.parse(json.toString());
    String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
    System.out.println("Pretty Json: " + prettyJsonString);

    entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

    post.setEntity(entity);
    //this is your response:

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);   
    System.out.println("Object Response: " + jo);

    JSONArray ab = new JSONArray(response);
    JSONObject cd = ab.getJSONObject(0); 

    System.out.println("Array Response: " + cd);
    System.out.println("Array Response: " + jo.getJSONArray("6f2159f998"));
    System.out.println("Connection Status: " + response.getStatusLine());
    return response.getStatusLine().toString();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you must confirm that the response data is valid JSON data. With some JSON check sites, you can easily find that your json is valid. After format:

`{
    "statusLine": {
        "reasonPhrase": "OK",
        "protocolVersion": {},
        "statusCode": 200
    },
    "protocolVersion": {},
    "locale": "en_IN",
    "entity": {
        "repeatable": false,
        "content": {}
    }
}`

Now, the problem is that this JSON data is a `JSON Object`, not a `JSON Array`. So, the sentence `JSONArray ab = new JSONArray(response);` will cause an error. If you want to get `statusLine` result, you can use the code below:

`JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
String statusLine = jo.getJSONObject("statusLine").toString();`

Comment: Do you have any complete program reference for this please

Comment: @GaneshRavikumar Sorry, there is no complete program reference. Maybe you can google it with keywords like Java JSON and have a full understand to using of Java JSON. May be the easier way to understand it is that ``{}`` in JSON data can be represented by JSONObject in Java and ``[]`` can be represented by JSONArray in Java.

Comment: Am getting only the status line. there are some thing data which need to be display. but they are not visible in this program. Kindly help me.